# API issue in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, calendly

So I have a container which pulls available times in a list from the Calendly API, when testing via web based solutions on chrome, it all works fine. However when testing on iOS devices, via TestFlight the container which holds the API call, is a grey box.

Very strange, tried everything I can find online, but can't get my head around this. The app is built in Flutter. Can anyone help?

Add Accept: application/json and Content-Type: application/json headers to the API group, didn't solve the issue.